# Robot Framework: access Robot's global variables from Python library code?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have some settings-type global vars that I'd like to be able to access from Python code. For example:

```
pybot --variable RESULTS_PATH:/wherever/this/points test.txt
```

Now, my module `logger.py` file needs to know the results_path to set up properly.

I know that I can initialize the logger with a variable, like

```
***Settings***
Library  logger  ${RESULTS_PATH}
```

And then in logger I'll be passed results_path:

```
 def __init__(self, results_path):
   # Whatever
```

However the problem with doing it this way for me is that I want to access and use the logger from both Python code and within test cases. So if I set it up this way, if I want to use the logger from Python code I run into the same problem of needing results_path to initialize the logger properly.

Are there any functions in the robot framework library that would allow me to grab the value of ${RESULTS_PATH} from Python code? What is the proper way to do something like this?

Right now, my workaround for the issue is to set RESULTS_PATH as an environment variable. So I have something like:

Run like:

```
RESULTS_PATH=/wherever/this/points pybot test.txt
```

#### File `test.txt`:

```
***Settings***
Library  logger
...
```

#### File `logger.py`:

```
results_path = os.environ["RESULTS_PATH"]
# Other set up stuff
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You will want to use rf's `BuiltIn` library, [for reference read the documentation as found here](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/autodoc/robot.libraries.html#module-robot.libraries.BuiltIn). This provides the keywords that are built into Robot Framework and so should reliably stay usable:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
results_path = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${RESULTS_PATH}")
```

Comment: I wonder if this code snippet could run standalone without pybot. Let's assume it is in a python file with name result.py. and we run this python file with "python result.py". The interpreter will tell an error "raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')". I wonder how to do the unittest like this code?

Comment: docs seem to have moved to https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/autodoc/robot.libraries.html#module-robot.libraries.BuiltIn